# Unique values in each column into a column with the number of it's occurrences, pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, aggregate, data-science

I have a data-set on a claim-level record.

[image: Data-frame Example]

And I want to create another dataframe with the occurrences of each unique value in one week.

[image: The new data-frame Example]

Say the table's name is (Claims.csv)

```
import pandas as pd
import dateutil
df = pd.read_csv("Claims.csv", encoding='utf-8')
```

Should I make a loop that goes through all my rows and save each unique value in a list then create the new array from this list, then again go through all the rows to get the number of values of it?
Or there's a built-in function in pandas that can do this, or a ready-made library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is function you're looking for

```
df['column_name'].value_counts()
```